# Getting HttpMessageNotReadableException: Cannot deserialize value of type ... from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)] in Test

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have some code like

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("assessment-payload-2.json");
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/submitAssessment")
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .content(resource.getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
  .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

that fails with

> [Test worker] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.AssessmentPayload` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)]

But I can confirm that I am able to parse the data correctly when I use the ObjectMapper

```
@Test
void readPayload() throws Exception {

  ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("assessment-payload-2.json");
  final var assessmentPayload =
    new ObjectMapper()
      .readValue(resource.getContentAsByteArray(), AssessmentPayload.class);
}
```

The controller is defined as

```
@PostMapping(
  path = "/submitAssessment",
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ApiResponse submitAssessment(
  @RequestBody AssessmentPayload payload, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
```

So everything seems to be in order but the test is failing because it seems to be seeing an array.

The content is not an array from what I can tell.  Even the `Body` value shows up as proper JSON

```
 Body = {
  "assessment": {
  ...
```

I also defined a global `@Bean CsvMapper`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out having the `@Bean CsvMapper` makes Spring MVC use that as the primary `JsonParser` implementation once I traced it through the debugger.  So the workaround for this was to remove the bean definition and instantiate the mapper when I need it.